# How to drag elements inside a zoomable content widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create an editable node diagram in a draggable/zoomable viewport (kind of like the node system in Blender). A user should be able to edit and drag the nodes.

I can't get the [PhotoView](https://github.com/renancaraujo/photo_view) (which I use as a viewport) to stay still when I actually want to drag a node within it. All of the `PhotoView`'s children are moving when only one widget - the node - should do so.

I've tried placing boxes listening to pointer events (to make them draggable) inside a `PhotoView`, but somehow, anything outside a centered area the size of the screen doesn't receive any touches.

Minimal code so far:

Creating the `PhotoViewController` (inside a State):

```dart
double scale = 1;
PhotoViewController controller;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  controller = PhotoViewController()
    ..outputStateStream.listen(listener);
}

void listener(PhotoViewControllerValue value) {
  setState(() {
    // store the scale in a local variable to drag widgets in relation to the zoom
    scale = value.scale;
  });
}
```

Building the viewport (also part of the State):

```dart
Offset position = Offset(0, 0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: PhotoView.customChild(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // vertical line
            Center(
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: 1,
                  height: 1000,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // horizontal line
            Center(
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: 1000,
                  height: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // box to debug the initial screen size
            Center(
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black12
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            // stack containing all nodes (only one in this case)
            Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // build a node...
                  Center(
                      child: Transform.translate( // offset the node
                          offset: position,
                          child: Listener( // make it a listener
                            child: DecoratedBox(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red
                              ),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 130,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text("Node",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 18.0
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // make the node listen to touch movements and eventually change its position
                            onPointerMove: (event) =>
                            {
                              setState(() =>
                              {
                                position +=
                                    event.delta.scale(1 / scale, 1 / scale)
                              })
                            },
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ],
        ),
        childSize: Size(10000, 10000),
        backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
        initialScale: 1.0,
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
```

At the moment, I kind of fixed the unintentional viewport drag by toggling a bool (whenever a node is touched/released) and overwriting the PhotoView's value.

Answer (score 0):

Switching from the [photo_view](https://github.com/renancaraujo/photo_view) package to pskink's [matrix_gesture_detector](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector) solved my issues. Though I now follow a different system: for every node, a new matrix is created (deriving from a main matrix, translated by the node's position). Matrices may be used inside a `Transform` widget to transform its child.

I achieved building a translatable viewport in which there is a draggable node carrying a clickable checkbox.
Some working minimal code:

```dart
import 'package:matrix_gesture_detector/matrix_gesture_detector.dart';
import 'package:vector_math/vector_math_64.dart' as vector;

...

  // following code is executed inside a State

  Matrix4 matrix = Matrix4.identity();
  ValueNotifier<int> notifier = ValueNotifier(0);
  vector.Vector3 nodePosition = vector.Vector3(50, 0, 0);
  bool check = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Node Diagram Demo'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (ctx, constraints) {
          return MatrixGestureDetector(
            shouldRotate: false,
            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
              matrix = MatrixGestureDetector.compose(matrix, tm, sm, null);
              notifier.value++;
            },
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              color: Color(0xff444444),
              child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: notifier,
                builder: (ctx, child) {
                  return Container(
                      width: double.infinity,
                      height: double.infinity,
                      child: Stack( // a stack in which all nodes are built
                        children: <Widget>[
                          buildCenter(),
                          buildNode()
                        ],
                      )
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }


  // I made this into a method so the transformed matrix can be calculated at runtime
  Widget buildNode() {
    // create a clone of the main matrix and translate it by the node's position
    Matrix4 ma = matrix.clone();
    ma.translate(nodePosition.x, nodePosition.y);

    return Transform(
        transform: ma, // transform the node using the new (translated) matrix
        child: MatrixGestureDetector(
            shouldRotate: false,
            shouldScale: false,
            onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
              Matrix4 change = tm;
              // move the node (in relation to the viewport zoom) when it's being dragged
              double sc = MatrixGestureDetector.decomposeToValues(matrix).scale;
              nodePosition += change.getTranslation() / sc;
              notifier.value++; // refresh view
            },
            // design a node holding a bool variable ('check')...
            child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.blue
                ),
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 100,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("Node",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 18.0
                        ),
                      ),
                      Checkbox(
                        onChanged: (v) =>
                        {
                          check = v,
                          notifier.value++ // refresh view
                        },
                        value: check,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }

  // build two lines to indicate a matrix origin
  Widget buildCenter() {
    return Transform(
        transform: matrix,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            // vertical line
            Center(
                child: Container(
                    width: 1,
                    height: 250,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white)
                )
            ),
            // horizontal line
            Center(
                child: Container(
                    width: 250,
                    height: 1,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white)
                )
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
```